# Django Rest Framework: "Invalid literal for in()" with a CharField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an API endpoint for user favorites. However, I have now hit an issue I cannot resolve.

I am getting an invalid literal error for a CharField when POSTing to the endpoint.

```
ValueError at /api/users/2/favourites/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'track'
```

Here is the serializer:

```
class FavouriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(
        read_only=True,
        default=CreateOnlyDefault(serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    )
    type = serializers.CharField(source='content_type')
    object = FavouriteObjectRelatedField(read_only=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='object_id')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        raise TypeError(validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Favourites
        fields = ('type', 'object', 'user', 'type', 'id')
```

I have verified that the error arises from the serializer and not the view by raising an exception in the `to_internal_value()` method in the serializer. This fires after the view.

I have checked my database to verify that there are no data errors.

One thing that may be causing the error (not sure how) is that I am using the [content types framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).

Therefore, here's the model:

```
class Favourites(models.Model):
    objects = FavouritesManager()

    user = models.ForeignKey('Profile.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('favorite')
        verbose_name_plural = _('favorites')
        unique_together = (('user', 'content_type', 'object_id'),)
```

The error occurs on the `type` field. I do not get this error if I change the field to a `IntegerField` and use integers for the data. Strangely, I also do not get the error if I turn the `id` field into a `CharField`. Thus, I believe it is something to do with the foreign key to `ContentType` but have no idea how.

You can view the full stacktrace [here](http://dpaste.com/0MK87T6).

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a `CharField`:

```
type = serializers.CharField(source='content_type')
```

While `content_type` is a `ForeignKey` to `ContentType` which primary key is an integer:

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
```

If you POST `type=track`, Django will try to cast `'track'` as an integer, which obviously fails.

Your type should be:

```
type = serializers.IntegerField(source='content_type')
```

And you should not POST `type=track`, but `type=5` for instance if the `id` of the `ContentType` row is `5`.

Try this on a shell to get the IDs of your content types:

```
>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> ContentType.objects.all().values_list()
[
    (1, 'auth', 'user'),
    (2, 'auth', 'permission'),
    (3, 'auth', 'group'),
    (4, 'contenttypes', 'contenttype'),
    (5, 'sessions', 'session'),
    ...
    (8, 'yourapp', 'yourmodel'),
    ...
]
```